# Reseller hosting with Windows Server 2008/IIS7 and SQL Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, sql-server-2008, web-hosting

I am looking for suggestions on a reseller hosting plan with Windows Server 2008/IIS7 and SQL Server.  I am currently with aspnix and looking for options, mainly due to continuous lack of support.  Support is definitely a criteria, as well as the option to migrate to VPS if needed.

Answer (score 1):

[Crystaltech](http://www.crystaltech.com/dotnet.aspx) has reseller plans with the features you mentioned. I've used them for years (not as a reseller) and have always been happy with their support.

Comment: I checked their offer and it's rather quirky, not a straight forward reseller offer by any stretch of imagination.

Comment: I'm assuming you saw this: http://www.crystaltech.com/resellers.aspx I don't know enough about reselling hosting to know what the quirky part is.

Comment: Usually you will see a well defined set of resources, a well known reseller control panel application (Plesk, Helm, etc.), and that's about it, you as a reseller can create your own plans, set your own prices, etc.  The system on the page you pointed out gives you a preset plan and price, a bit unusual.

Comment: You might talk to them to see how they address these concerns. It is true that they have their own control panel, though.